# Give me any example for getting an image from gallery in windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I am new to windows phone 8 development so any one can you please help me in getting the image which is stored into the camera roll (sdcard). And i should retrieve the image by using the path of the image which i have stored in to the sd card.So kindly provide me an example.

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1):

You can use [PhotoChooserTask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.tasks.photochoosertask%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

For imagepath just call

```
 photoChooserTask.Completed += OnCameraTaskCompleted;

   private void OnCameraTaskCompleted(object sender, PhotoResult e)
    {
        if (e.TaskResult == TaskResult.OK)
        {
           stream ImagePath = e.ChosenPhoto
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this link

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394019(v=vs.105).aspx

```
    photoChooserTask = new PhotoChooserTask();
    photoChooserTask.Completed += new EventHandler<PhotoResult>(photoChooserTask_Completed);
    photoChooserTask.Show();

    void photoChooserTask_Completed(object sender, PhotoResult e)
    {
       if (e.TaskResult == TaskResult.OK)
       {
        MessageBox.Show(e.ChosenPhoto.Length.ToString());

        //Code to display the photo on the page in an image control named myImage.
        //System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage bmp = new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage();
        //bmp.SetSource(e.ChosenPhoto);
        //myImage.Source = bmp;
       }
    }
```

hopes this might help ....

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I need to get the path of the image while i am  storing the image into the camera roll. Can u please help me.

Answer (score 0):

In windows phone you can not get gallery image path. If you use GetPath() method then it display gallery image name.Try following link....... 
  [getting the path of the stored image in windows phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18572931/getting-the-path-of-the-stored-image-in-windows-phone)
   http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/wpapps/en-US/264ef9e7-b123-4e76-9fd7-b1ff924995c3/getting-path-of-image-in-camera-roll-in-wp8-using-c?forum=wpdevelop