# getting the path of the stored image in windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I am storing the image into camera roll

```
library.SavePictureToCameraRoll(DateTime.Now.ToString() + ".jpg", e.ImageStream);
```

my Problem is How can i get the path of this image after storing this image.

Answer (score 4):

On WP8, `SavePictureToCameraRoll` returns a `Picture` object on which you can call the `GetPath` method (don't forget to add the `using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media.PhoneExtensions;`)

```
var picture = lib.SavePicture(string.Format("test.jpg"), ms);
var filePath = picture.GetPath();
```

Unfortunately, on WP7 there is no way to get the path, because `SavePictureToCameraRoll` doesn't return anything.